# How to average the minimums of a group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

If I select the minimum of every group:

```
SELECT MIN(price) FROM Products GROUP BY category
```

How can I get the average of this minimums? I understand that

```
SELECT AVG(MIN(price)) FROM Products GROUP BY category
```

won't work. Any help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find minimums for all categories and then apply the average function to them.

```
select avg(m) as AvgOfAllMins from 
(
select category,min(price) as m from products
group by category) T;
```

See the result from [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5prcFnuV9HzCymXmwwqMhS/0).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in two steps:

```
WITH min_prices as 
(
  SELECT category, MIN(price) as min_price 
  FROM Products 
  GROUP BY category
)
SELECT category, AVG(min_price) as avg_min_price
FROM min_prices
GROUP BY category
```

Comment: Note that the AVG of MIN for a specific category simply is the MIN value.

Comment: @jarlh good point :)

Comment: I.e. skip the outer GROUP BY, and remove category from the SELECT clause, and you have the average of _all_ MIN values.